# Aggregation on top 100 documents sorted by a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to do a terms aggregation on top 100 documents sorted on a field (not relevance score!).

I know how to do the aggregation:

```
{  
    "query": {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "mydata_agg" : {
            "terms": {
                "field" : "title"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I know how to get top 100 documents sorted on a field:

```
{
    "query": { 
        "match_all": {} 
    }, 
    "sort": {
        "units_sold": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    },
    "size": 100
}
```

But how do I run the terms aggregation on those 100 sorted documents? I could use a range filter but then I need to specify myself the cutoff value of **units_sold** that results in top 100 documents. results. I prefer to do everything in one query. Is that possible?

I have searched for couple hours but was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The term aggregation creates buckets, and we need to sort the outcome of the first aggregation. this can be done using `bucket_sort`.Read this [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html) for more information.